# MvvmCross throwing InvalidStackFrameException

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross to develop an ios app. Everything worked fine until suddenly I got the following exception:

```
Mono.Debugger.Soft.InvalidStackFrameException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the specified stack frame is no longer valid.
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.ErrorHandler (System.Object sender, Mono.Debugger.Soft.ErrorHandlerEventArgs args) [0x00076] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/VirtualMachine.cs:301 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive (CommandSet command_set, Int32 command, Mono.Debugger.Soft.PacketWriter packet) [0x000f9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:1448 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.StackFrame_GetValues (Int64 thread_id, Int64 id, System.Int32[] pos) [0x00026] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:2225 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.StackFrame.GetValue (Mono.Debugger.Soft.LocalVariable var) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/StackFrame.cs:122 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.VariableValueReference.get_Value () [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/VariableValueReference.cs:68 
  at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ValueReference.OnCreateObjectValue (Mono.Debugging.Client.EvaluationOptions options) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/ValueReference.cs:138 
  at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ValueReference.CreateObjectValue (Mono.Debugging.Client.EvaluationOptions options) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/ValueReference.cs:106 Mono.Debugger.Soft.InvalidStackFrameException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the specified stack frame is no longer valid.
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.ErrorHandler (System.Object sender, Mono.Debugger.Soft.ErrorHandlerEventArgs args) [0x00076] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/VirtualMachine.cs:301 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive (CommandSet command_set, Int32 command, Mono.Debugger.Soft.PacketWriter packet) [0x000f9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:1448 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.StackFrame_GetValues (Int64 thread_id, Int64 id, System.Int32[] pos) [0x00026] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Connection.cs:2225 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.StackFrame.GetValue (Mono.Debugger.Soft.LocalVariable var) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/StackFrame.cs:122 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.VariableValueReference.get_Value () [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging.Soft/VariableValueReference.cs:68 
  at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ValueReference.OnCreateObjectValue (Mono.Debugging.Client.EvaluationOptions options) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/ValueReference.cs:138 
  at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ValueReference.CreateObjectValue (Mono.Debugging.Client.EvaluationOptions options) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-license-sync/c5f82958/source/monodevelop/main/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/ValueReference.cs:106
```

It is important to say that this only happens on the device, everything works perfectly on the simulator...
I have fiddled with the code to come to a conclusion once I removed the following code everything worked:

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (MainTable, RecomendationTemplate.Key, RecomendationTemplate.Key);
            MainTable.Source = source;
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainPage, MainPageViewModel> ();
            set.Bind (source).To (vm => vm.Recomendations);
            set.Apply ();
```

After that I have tried to use a difference cell template. I started with an empty one and it worked. but once I added the DelayBind mehtod I kept on getting the following exception... I have no idea how to move forward from here.

Comment: This stacktrace looks like it is in the xamarin debugger stack - perhaps try their support directly or via their forums.

Comment: @stuart I have found a thread similar to my problem (http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2364/mono-debugger-soft-invalidstackframeexception) (although in android) but my app also crashed also when I created an ipa and deploying it to the device...

Comment: @Amit Have you tried a release build? This looks a lot like a crash in the debugger.

Comment: @Krumelur I have tried deploying to my device using an ad-hoc license, so I guess yes :)

Comment: Well, you can deploy with or without debug information. You should try the latter.